# How can I use a nested name as the __getitem__ index of the previous iterable in list comprehensions?

Tags: python, nested, list-comprehension

I want to use two for-loops inside a list-comprehension, but I want to use the name of the second as an index of the first iterable. How can I do that?

Example:

```
l = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
[x for x in l[i] for i in range(len(l))]
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 2, in <module>
NameError: name 'i' is not defined
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the order of your `for` loops mixed up. They should be listed in *nesting order*, the same order you'd use if you wrote out the loops normally:

```
[x for i in range(len(l)) for x in l[i]]
```

When in doubt, write out the loops like you'd write them when using statements. Your list comprehension tried to do this:

```
for x in l[i]:
    for i in range(len(l)):
        x
```

which makes it more obvious that you tried to access `i` before you defined it.